# How to bind bing maps in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, bing-maps, fluttermap

I Used google Maps in Flutter and it works out of box for us. I am able to do with the help of documentation like how to use google maps in Flutter But i want to Use Bing Maps in Flutter and all properties like current loc. ,Drawing polylines,custom marker,popUp on marker.  Can someone suggest me where to learn thiese things or any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Bing Maps map control for Flutter. One option might be to use the open source Flutter map control: https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map

Details on how to directly access Bing Maps tiles can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/directly-accessing-the-bing-maps-tiles

The open source Flutter Map control has an example that uses Azure Maps as well, which is another Microsoft mapping platform to consider.